# What is the meaning of "Patch on your jeans"?

Tags: meaning, idioms, slang

What does it mean to say "those guys are not a patch on our jeans" as Biden said here:

> I’ve long said — and I mean this — I have never, ever, ever been more optimistic about America’s prospects than I am today. Never. Never. I’ve traveled to over 140 countries around the world. As I was — I’ll paraphrase the phrase of my old neighborhood: The rest of the countries — the world is not a “patch on our jeans” if we do what we want to do and we need to do.
>
> [Remarks by President Biden on Rebuilding Our Infrastructure and Creating Good-Paying Jobs](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/speeches-remarks/2023/01/04/remarks-by-president-biden-on-rebuilding-our-infrastructure-and-creating-good-paying-jobs/)

A web search didn't reveal much.

Comment: There's a UK English expression "[not a patch on someone/something](https://www.macmillanthesaurus.com/not-a-patch-on-something)", meaning not nearly as good as, or in no way comparable to; it is found in late 19th century texts. I can't find an etymology but I guess it might mean too dissimilar to be suitable to use in repairing, or might refer to the use of small otherwise-useless pieces of fabric for mending (i.e. worse even than that). I don't know if the quote is a garbled version of that.

Comment: Stuart it may be that idiom means "isn't even capable of helping", not worthy even as a patch.

Comment: I'll just note that a "patch" on your "jeans" is, in a literal sense, a piece of denim fabric used to repair a hole or worn spot on a pair denim pants (which are commonly worn by young people in the US).  I don't know if it's relevant in this case, but sometimes such patches are used, when they are not needed, to "style" clothing.

Comment: Answer to come maybe, but meanwhile: *Biden commended Obama as a great president compared with his successor, using an insult from his childhood in Scranton, Pennsylvania. “You’re still driving him crazy because he knows he isn’t a patch on your jeans," Biden said.* https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/elections/2020/10/31/obama-biden-make-first-joint-appearance/6101339002/

Comment: As in, Trump is not the jeans; he's not even worthy of being a patch on the jeans.

Comment: Used sarcastically. It's unlikely he was trying to be antisarcastic when talking about the literal rest of the world.

Comment: Many idioms have different meaning when used sarcastically. Eg "good job, genius!"

Answer (score 7):

Here, with a bit of surrounding content for context, is the relevant portion of the transcript of Biden's remarks, as recorded in "[Remarks by President Biden on Rebuilding Our Infrastructure and Creating Good-Paying Jobs](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/speeches-remarks/2023/01/04/remarks-by-president-biden-on-rebuilding-our-infrastructure-and-creating-good-paying-jobs/)" on the whitehouse.gov website:

> Together, we’re proving our best days are ahead of us. And I mean this from the bottom of my heart. I’ve been doing this a long time, folks. Our best days are ahead us; they’re not behind us.
>
> I’ve long said — and I mean this — I have never, ever, ever been more optimistic about America’s prospects than I am today. Never. Never. I’ve traveled to over 140 countries around the world. As I was — I’ll paraphrase the phrase of my old neighborhood: The rest of the countries — **the world is not a “patch on our jeans”** if we do what we want to do and we need to do.
>
> It’s never been a good bet to bet against America. It’s never been more true than today.

The expression is not one I've ever encountered, but the sense that Biden was reaching for seems fairly clear: the rest of the world can't measure up to the promise, greatness, etc., etc. of the United States. This is standard political blather—a garden-variety appeal to the audience's vanity regarding the specialness of its nation. In this context, "the world is not a patch on our jeans" expresses the same boastful (or patriotic, depending on your perspective) idea as the would the more familiar idiomatic wording "the [rest of the] world can't hold a candle to us."

At a guess, I imagine that Biden intended to allude to a time in the late 1960s and early 1970s when it was briefly fashionable to add patches of material—often in bright or contrasting colors—to blue jeans for aesthetic rather than utilitarian effect. You can get a sense of this style from the picture on the [back cover of Neil Young's 1970 LP, *After the Gold Rush*](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/336292297148536654/?amp_client_id=CLIENT_ID%28_%29&mweb_unauth_id=&simplified=true). Groovy.

Prior to that period, people generally used patches of denim taken from another (discarded) pair of jeans to cover splits or holes in a well-worn but still serviceable pair. Alternatively, they bought and used iron-on patches of denim-like material to cover such defects. But invoking these utilitarian senses of "patches on jeans" doesn't make much sense in the context of Biden's speech, since his argument isn't that the U.S. is worn out and full of holes that other countries can't serve as patches for.

---

Another possibility is that Biden may simply have free-associated "on our jeans" with the (rather rare in the United States) idiomatic expression "not a patch on," figuratively meaning "not in the same league or at the same level with." Here are three instances of that shorter expression.

From "[Quarterly Review of Records](https://books.google.com/books?id=c-E5AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA110&dq=%22not+a+patch%22+jeans&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiK1dO497P8AhVQJUQIHRrJBF0Q6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22not%20a%20patch%22%20jeans&f=false)," in *The [London] Gramophone* (August 1925):

> De Groot has his moments, but **he is not a patch on Marek Weber** and occasionally he commits atrocious solecisms ; his religious record ... who with the Geiger Orchestra and Jean Lensen have given us some capital records this quarter .

From "[Extension of Remarks of Hon. Karl E. Mundt of South Dakota](https://books.google.com/books?id=Jq6J_3eTO0gC&pg=SL1-PA1068&dq=%22not+a+patch%22+jeans&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiK1dO497P8AhVQJUQIHRrJBF0Q6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=%22not%20a%20patch%22%20jeans&f=false)" (February 5, 1958) in *Congressional Record—Appendix* (1958):

> Many more members of Parliament have commercial connections with the United States. A good Tory example is Sir Keith Joseph, an engineering contractor who met his wife, a lively Wellesley student, on a United States selling trip. Joseph has some criticism of the United States ("**Your civil service is not a patch on ours**") but is an ardent advocate of American industrial management.

And from "[Martyr to a Foul Cause](https://books.google.com/books?id=2LQPAQAAMAAJ&q=%22not+a+patch%22+jeans&dq=%22not+a+patch%22+jeans&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiK1dO497P8AhVQJUQIHRrJBF0Q6AF6BAgKEAI)," in the *New York Times Book Review* (1965) [combined snippets]:

> His public broadcasts were more maddening than convincing; he [William Joyce, "Lord Haw-Haw"] did not, in fact, know Britain well. Clever as he was, **he was not a patch on Jean-Herold Paquis**, his French opposite number for the Nazis. Indeed, most of the propaganda effort was wasted.

As these examples suggest, "not  patch on" is chiefly a British idiom. John Ayto, *Oxford Dictionary of English Idioms*, third edition (2009) has this entry for it:

> **not a patch on** greatly inferior to. *British informal* | **1991 Mavis Nicholson** *Martha Jane & Me* We thought the uniform of our soldiers was 'pathetic', not a patch on the American soldiers' uniform.

And *Longman Dictionary of English Idioms* (1979) has this:

> **not be a patch on** *coll[oquial]* to be not nearly so good as: *the paintings here are good, but they're not a patch on the ones that we saw in London* | <PATCH in this idiom means a small unimportant piece of cloth that is used to mend a worn out or torn garment

---

**Update (January 7, 2023):** Since I first posted this answer, Tinfoil Hat, in a comment beneath the posted question, has pointed out a highly relevant earlier instance in which Biden used the same phrase. From Bart Jansen, "['Outhustle the Other Side': Obama Urges Michigan Voters to Oust Trump in First Joint Appearance with Biden](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/elections/2020/10/31/obama-biden-make-first-joint-appearance/6101339002/)," in *USA Today* (October 31, 2020):

> Biden commended Obama as a great president compared with his successor, using an insult from his childhood in Scranton, Pennsylvania.
>
> "You’re still driving him crazy because he knows **he isn’t a patch on your jeans**," Biden said.

Use a not-widely-recognized expression once, and it could be a spur-of-the-moment formulation (like "covfefe"). Use it twice, 26 months apart, and it seems far more likely to be a local or family idiom—a set phrase in the speaker's vocabulary. Whether the expression "not a patch on [one's] jeans" was widespread in Scranton in Biden's childhood or limited to his school, neighborhood, or household, I now think that it is genuinely idiomatic for him and probably for others in his home town as well.

Comment: The second option would be widely understood in Britain. Cambridge dictionary has: not be a patch on something
idiom UK informal
to be much less good than something.       This would have been the basis of my answer but you have done it well instead.